# How to get Availability SLA report of web test in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, report, azure-application-insights

We are using Application Insight and have added a couple of web tests to monitor our site. The web tests are all run from three locations every 5 minutes and all three locations need to fail within 5 minutes for the alert to go off.

Is there some report in Application Insights that we could use to report availability for the previous month to our customer? We would need the availability percentage with at least one decimal.

UPDATE:
Based on the answer by @ZakiMa I ended up with the following query:

```
let lastmonthstart = startofmonth(now(), -1);
let lastmonthend = endofmonth(lastmonthstart);
availabilityResults
| where timestamp between(lastmonthstart .. lastmonthend)
| summarize failurecount=countif(success == 0), successcount=countif(success == 1) by name, bin(timestamp, 5m)
| project failure = iff(failurecount > 0 and successcount == 0, 1, 0), name, bin(timestamp, 5m)
| summarize totalFailures = sum(failure), totalTests = count(failure) by name
| project ["Name"] = name, ["SLA"] = todouble(totalTests - totalFailures) / todouble(totalTests) * 100
| order by ["SLA"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can calculate SLA using Application Insights Analytics. Click on "Analytics" menu item on your overview page and use the following query:

```
availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| summarize _successCount=todouble(countif(success == 1)),
            _errorCount=todouble(countif(success == 0)),
            _totalCount=todouble(count()) by name
| project
          ["Name"] = name,
          ["SLA"] = _successCount / _totalCount * 100
| order by ["SLA"]
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

And then you can pin it to your dashboard (there is a pin icon in the top right corner):

[image]

This is just an example - here you can find full analytics query language reference - it's quite powerful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference. You can adjust to your definition of SLA.

**EDIT**: Here is an example of a query which is closer to your question

```
availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
// check whether location failed within 5m bin
| summarize _failure=iff(countif(success == 0)>0, 1, 0) by name, location, bin(timestamp, 5m)
// check whether all locations failed within 5m bin
| summarize _failureAll=iff(sum(_failure)>=3, 1, 0) by name, bin(timestamp, 5m)
// count all failed 5 minute bins and total number of bins
| summarize _failuresCount=sum(_failureAll), _totalCount=count() by name
| project ["Name"] = name,
          ["SLA"] = todouble(_totalCount - _failuresCount) / todouble(_totalCount) * 100
| order by ["SLA"]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works great and the instructions were 100% helpful. As always with reporting, when you get something you just want more:-). Now I'll see if I can figure out how to change the where clause to get data for the previous full month, or even data grouped by month for the last 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Application insights has "Availability" metric which you can plot in MetricsExplorer and then pin it to your dashboard. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

To create an SLA 'report' over more than 1 application insights item, do the following (also works for just one ai).

In a log analytics workspace: add a parameters item. Add a time range picker and a resource picker. With the resource picker, select as data source: Query, and enter the following Azure Resource Graph query:

```
where type =~ 'microsoft.insights/components'
| summarize by id, name
```

Underneath, add a query item with the following query:

```
availabilityResults
| summarize Uptime= avg(toint(success))*100 by bin(timestamp, 366d), 
| sort by Uptime asc, appName asc
```

Also select as the following parameters:

- Data source: Logs
- Resource type: Application Insights
- Resource: the name of your resource picker parameter
- Time range: the name of your time range picker.

Then choose what kind of visualisation: you can play with this. I recommend Graph - Honeycomb. For the Uptime field, set `Units` to `Percentage`, `Style` to `Decimal` and `Maximum fractional digits` to 3 for a pretty `99,xxx%` uptime percentage.

There you go!